# no window.__coverage__ object is created by istanbul + phantomJS

Tags: unit-testing, gulp, phantomjs, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm trying to use the following stack for my client side testing,
however, it seems like istanbul, aside from generating spec files, doesn't do much.

I've tried following various examples from:

[here](https://github.com/SBoudrias/gulp-istanbul/blob/master/README.md#browser-testing), [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-phantomjs-istanbul#gulp) and [here](https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/measuring-clientside-javascript-test-coverage-with-istanbul)

however, no matter what I do, istanbul doesn't seem to create an in memory reference of the `window.__coverage__ object and I'm unable to parse the output due to this.`

The `pre-test` task shown under the gulpfile.js, does generate some funky instrumented files, which doesn't seem to do or go anywhere.

Please advise

#### task configuration

- gulp
- gulp-mocha-phantomjs
- gulp-istanbul

#### client side

- sinon
- mocha

### gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('pre-test', function () {
    return gulp.src(['tests/ar.config.js'])
    // Covering files
        .pipe(istanbul())
        // Write the covered files to a temporary directory
        .pipe(gulp.dest('coverage/'));
});
```

`gulp.task('test', ['inject', 'pre-test'], function () {
    return gulp
        .src('index.html', {read: false})
        .pipe(mochaPhantomJS(
            {
                reporter: 'spec',
                phantomjs: {
                    hooks: 'mocha-phantomjs-istanbul',
                    coverageFile: './coverage/coverage.json'
                }
            }))
        .pipe(istanbul.writeReports())
});`

### mocha-phantomjs-istanbul

```
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');

function collectCoverage(page) {
    // istanbul stores coverage in global.__coverage__
    var coverage = page.evaluate(function () {
        return window.__coverage__;
    });

    // fail gracefully when we don't have coverage
    if (!coverage) {
        console.log("no coverage found!")
        return;
    }

    // read coverageFile from mocha-phantomjs args
    var phantomOpts = JSON.parse(system.args[system.args.length - 1]);
    var coverageFile = phantomOpts.coverageFile || 'coverage/coverage.json';

    // write coverage to file
    var json = JSON.stringify(coverage);
    fs.write(coverageFile, json);
}

// beforeStart and afterEnd hooks for mocha-phantomjs
module.exports = {
    afterEnd: function (runner) {
        collectCoverage(runner.page);
    }
};
```

### output

```
...
✓ test x
✓ test y
✓ test z

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|


=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 100% ( 0/0 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually after some tinkering, I've realized that I was covering my test files instead of the source files I was testing.

### gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var istanbul = require('gulp-istanbul');
var mochaPhantomJS = require('gulp-mocha-phantomjs');
var istanbulReport = require('gulp-istanbul-report');

gulp.task('instrument', function () {
    return gulp.src(['src/js/**/*.js'])
        // Covering files
        .pipe(istanbul({
            coverageVariable: '__coverage__'
        }))
        // instrumented files will go here
        .pipe(gulp.dest('coverage/'))
});

gulp.task('test', ['instrument', 'inject'], function () {
    return gulp
        .src('index.html', {read: false})
        .pipe(mochaPhantomJS({
            reporter: ["spec"],
            phantomjs: {
                useColors: true,
                hooks: 'mocha-phantomjs-istanbul',
                coverageFile: './coverage/coverage.json'
            }
        }))
        .on('finish', function () {
            gulp.src("./coverage/coverage.json")
                .pipe(istanbulReport({
                    reporters: ['text', 'html']
                }))
        });
});

var paths = {
    "javascript": ["coverage/**/*.js"],
    tests: ["tests/**/*.js"]
};

gulp.task('inject', ['instrument'], function (cb) {
    return gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(inject(
            gulp.src(paths.javascript,{read: false}), {
                relative: true
            }))
        .pipe(inject(
            gulp.src(paths.tests, {read: false}), {
                relative: true,
                starttag: "<!-- inject:tests:js -->"
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});
```

I wrote the following post explaining the full process of the testing methodology I was trying to achieve, should anyone would like to hear the theory behind all of this:

http://blog.silicak.es/2016-07-07-testing-browser-gulp-phantomJS-mocha-istanbul

Comment: Future readers should be able to read your answer on SO and apply it without having to read an external link. Please edit your answer so that people don't have to follow the link to know the substance of the solution.